# Monitor network traffic/usage by PORT

Tags: network-monitoring

I apologize in advance if this is out of topic.

I am currently using Icinga and Cacti to monitor machines and the network respectively. While I have no big issues with this setup, I would really like to have the option to monitor network traffic BY PORT in real time.

Is there a utility that does this? I only know of Paesler and Solar Winds, but anything non open source is out of the question for now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Physical network port, or TCP/UDP port?

Comment: Does your router support Netflow or the like?

Comment: @Hyppy TCP/UDP Port is what I meant. Should have clariffied.

Comment: @joeqwerty No it does not. We have a CISCO router but it is CPE from the telecom provider and we do not have access. We use a simle server with Zeroshell for routing/firewall. So, no Netflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked for ideas and... here is mine.

To solve your problem, you've two very limiting conditions:

1. You're unable to take hands on your Cisco ('cause it's not yours and its configuration cannot be changed to suite your needs);
2. You cannot change (at least, not easily) the way Zeroshell is working (due to the very nature of Zeroshell itself [it's quite complex to rebuild Zeroshell to suite your needs [see below]).

On the other end as you want REAL_TIME_MONITORING and PER-PORT-TRAFFIC-ACCOUNTING you're mostly forced to have at least one point (one network interface) where:

3. All the traffic will be flowing, so for you to "account" the all of it;
4. the interface is "owned" by some equipment you can manage.

What I have done in such situations is to *REPLACE* the existing appliance (in your case: Zeroshell; in my case various hardware appliances from various vendors) with something I can fully manage without constraints: a common linux box with at least two interfaces properly configured to route/firewall traffic.

Let's suppose this could be OK for you (...even tough I understand that could be an issue, for you, due to the initial setup-efforts).

*IF* such a machine is available, *THEN* I'd add to the set of software to install on it:

- [IPTRAF](http://iptraf.seul.org/): despite its age, it's still perfectly able to gives out REAL-TIME data from  your network interfaces. It provides a character-user-interface, so it can be launched remotely, within a simple SSH connection (no web, no big GUI libraries, etc.);
- [NTOP](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/):  from the official website: "*...a network traffic probe that shows the network usage, similar to what the popular top Unix command does...*". NTOP is way much feature-rich than IPTRAF. Definitely more powerful (but more complex to configure/install than a single "*apt-get install*" or "*yum install*")

As clearly stated, both tools above provides good **REAL-TIME** data (as you asked in your question). Anyway, I'm quite confident that you need ***ALSO*** asynchronous data: I'm sure you want also to be able to check something like: "*who were the hosts/MACs that generated/consumed most of the traffic, yesterday? And for which protocols?*", probably drilling down such data back to a single IP/MAC/PORT, and down to a granularity of.... 1 minute. Don't you? In such a case I strongly reccomend:

- [PMACCT](http://pmacct.net/): from the official website: "*...pmacct is a small set of passive network monitoring tools to measure, account, classify, aggregate and export IPv4 and IPv6 traffic..*". Please note that PMACCT can solve a wide range of problems, most of them suited for big/large ISP/operators. Nevertheless, it can run perfectly of your linux-box and account for traffic flowing along its interfaces. With a configuration like this:

-

```
host:~# cat /etc/pmacct/pmacctd.conf

interface: eth0
daemonize: true
aggregate: src_mac,dst_mac,src_host,dst_host,proto,src_port,dst_port

ports_file: /etc/pmacct/ports.list 

plugins: mysql

sql_user: pmacct
sql_passwd: sqlpassword
sql_db: pmacct
sql_table: acct_v4_%Y_%m_%d
[...]
```

it can easily keep track of traffic flowing along eth0 in a mysql table, so for you to easily check what happened on your network with a common/simple SQL-query.

Just to give you some real numbers, I've succesfully used PMACCT on a server with a XEON X3350; 4GB of RAM; 4 broadcom GigaEth interfaces; nearly 70 VLANs configured on eth0 and pmacct listening on all of them; +/- 300GB of various IP traffic routed on a daily basis; PMACCT generating accounting EVERY_MINUTE, for EVERY_VLAN, for EVERY tuple (src_mac, dst_mac, src_ip, dst_ip, src_port, dst_port); +/- 60.000.000 accounting records per day. 
All of this, without any issue (but writing on text-files, not in MySQL). In smaller environments, anyway, there are no problems in writing directly to MySQL.

Also, please note that thanks to PMACCT I keep track of *EACH* IP addresses seen on my networks, on a daily basis (in other words: I know that 10.29.19.89 have not been seen since july 16th 2014; 172.17.1.45 have never been seen [since the start of PMACCT accounting]; etc.).

Also on PMACCT: I have configured the ethernet switch connecting my main Internet-gateway, to "mirror" its traffic to a free port, where I've plugged an ad-hoc linux-box accounting all the Internet traffic (a 1GEth link). No issue at all.

A final note about PMACCT: should you (or some other readers) wonder why I **NOT** choosed some more common NETFLOW/IPFIX probe/collector, the reason is very simple: PMACCT is the only one I've found being able to account also MAC-addresses.

Answer (score -2):

this program can monitor traffic by port 10-Strike Bandwidth Monitor
(http://www.10-strike.com/bandwidth-monitor/)
another andvantage is that it displays all monitoring results into diagrams and graphs in real time
Visit the program's webpage, there are a lot of screenshots of it