# Log LAN bandwidth per IP (with command line output)

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring

I have a local samba server and I need from which IP most bandwidth is generated. I would like to be able to pump that data do influx so I need a commandline tool giving me some sort of straightforward output that I could work with using python for example.

There are some tools I've already exploread but all of them are either realtime monitors (which I don't want) or are uncapable of giving me a "per ip" statistics.

My case is simple -> single server, single network card so it's a central point to log data. All I need is a simple output in return, like:

```
10.10.10.10 -> 35234234 bytes sent
```

(average throughput will be fine as well).
Any clues ? (I'm not using ip tables)

I looked at iptraf-ng , itop - none of those allowed me go get command line output. (i don't need realtime bandwith)

Comment: Please, give a look to this answer ( http://serverfault.com/a/653332 , ALL the answer), as it looks to me that PMACCT might fit your needs. Let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Long and continuous load can produce more accounting that a bursted high-speed requests, so it's complicated, the time should be taken into account.

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli I looked at PMACCT site and it sure looks like a solution. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @DamianoVerzulli `pmacct` turned out to be a proper tool for the job.

I started `pmacctd` on my central server writing filtered data to memory (using memory plugin). Then I used `pmacct` command line tool to get this data in csv format.

In the end all I wanted is to pump this data info InfluxDB, so some `python` + csv data from `pmacct` worked without problems.

To get the counter periodicaly I used cron (with `pmacct` clearing counters after every readout).

Perhaps it's not the most elegant solution since it utilizes a `pmacctd`,`pmacct`,`python`,`cron` but works!

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

`iftop`, `trafshow`, and so on. Are you banned by google ?

Comment: any help with iftop - how to get a command line output with it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, all of these tools lack batch mode, so you have to HUP 'em programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to reply to drookie's answer, so this is going in the answer field.

@drookie -- they don't want real-time monitoring, although that would probably be their best option.  They might be able to gather bandwidth information from a switch and map the switch port to a user.

Comment: Imagine I have 3 dozens of managed switches, about thousand ports in total. Even if they are managed, and I can access the SNMP counters, how am I supposed to determine, which servers's traffic is the port most busy with ? I'm afraid your apprioach is wrong by design. The load has to be measured on the source to be able to determine what client are the most traffoc-consuming.

Comment: Given that it's a single server with a single NIC, I highly doubt that they have multiple dozens of managed switches.

Comment: This is a crippled logic. Single server and single NIC is telling nothing about the number of ports.